# Add query timeout in Elastic native query - springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How can I add query timeout in the below Native Seach Query?

```
final QueryBuilder contentTagQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .filter( QueryBuilders.termQuery("tenantId" , "en"));
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQuery(contentTagQuery);
query.setMaxResults(1);

SearchHits<Content> searchHits =
         elasticsearchOperations.search(
                        query, Content.class,
                        IndexCoordinates.of("index"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use spring-data-elasticsearch version >= `4.2.x` to be able to set a timeout.

```java
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQuery(contentTagQuery);
query.setMaxResults(1);
query.setTimeout(xx);
```

[This PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/572) was merged in 4.2.x version.

In **4.2.x**, `NativeSearchQuery` extends `AbstractQuery` and `AbstractQuery` has a [`setTimeout()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/d4052c49513f69f3ddfe042a8da08cac220a192d/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/AbstractQuery.java#L283) method which accepts a `TimeValue`.

**4.3.x** onwards, `NativeSearchQuery` extends `BaseQuery` and `BaseQuery` also has the [`setTimeout()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/3e950b8053c4e4b769b68ae86ed3e6d783102537/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/BaseQuery.java#L365) method which accepts a `Duration`.

Comment: I tried this, but getting this error=== 13:18:50.342 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter - Uncaught exception thrown
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/core/TimeValue ,,,, I am on 4.3.3 version of spring-data-elasticsearch and 7.14 elasticsearch

Comment: As I mentioned, 4.3.x onwards the `setTimeout()` method accepts a `Duration` and not a `TimeValue`. `public void setTimeout(@Nullable Duration timeout)`. Try setting a `Duration` in the `setTimeout()` method. For ex, to set 60 seconds timeout - `query.setTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));`

Comment: Yes, I am using the same  ```NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQuery(contentTagQuery);
            query.setMaxResults(1);
            query.setTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2));```